# What are the downsides of the Olympus Anti-shock Shutter Release (electronic front curtain shutter) on the M10 Mark ii?

Tags: olympus, micro-four-thirds, shutter-release, electronic-shutter

From what I understand this uses an electronic front curtain shutter, which I do not know how does it work.

Does it present the same disadvantages as a regular electronic shutter? - which are:

- banding when there is fluorescent lighting
- rolling shutter / slow scanning on rapidly moving subjects
- less bits for storing color information (this happens in some panasonics when using the electronic shutter, maybe it also applies to other cameras, I do not know.)

Comment: Interesting question and was wondering the same since the E-M10 Mark III comes in Single-Shot Anti-Shock drive mode by default.

Answer (score 4):

Electronic front curtain is different from an electronic shutter. An electronic front curtain simply de-energizes the entire sensor and then it turns on to start the image recording. The image recording is then ended with the normal rear curtain.

This is different from an electronic shutter where the image recording is started/ended by a rolling readout (clearing/activating) of the pixel rows which can cause the "rolling shutter" effect.

Answer (score 1):

On my Olympus E-M5 Mark II the Anti-Shock feature (I set it on 0s) causes banding in the sky when shutter speed is 1/160s - 1/320s.

[image]
<sub><sup>Original: https://abload.de/image.php?img=bildschirmfoto2021-12mpjp6.png</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a disadvantage in using it. I see it as the same as mirror lockup in my DSLR. I use it all the time, especially when doing macro photography.

Comment: I don't *think* there is, either, and I use it too... but an answer should probably back that up with some research (referenced or empirical). I would do some tests myself, but I don't have a body that does fully electronic shutter to compare against. :)

Comment: There is really no relation with mirror lockup which doesn't affect the shutter at all. On the other hand *Anti-Shock* modes on Olympus cameras change the way the shutter does its work. Remember than in a mirrorless, it is open while framing and usually closes while the sensor charge is flushed and then reopens.